# Can fasting-induced autophagy impact vitiligo progression?

Tags: dermatology, vitiligo, cells, autophagy

I recently came across a study titled "A Protective Role for Autophagy in Vitiligo" published in 2012, which is quite intriguing ([source](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/33767135/)). However, the level of detail and technicality of the study is beyond my comprehension. I am uncertain if the term autophagy is only fasting induced or if also encompasses cell death (caused by autoimmune diseases).

Despite my limited understanding, the study and its captivating figures have sparked my curiosity.

[image: Figures]

Could fasting induced autophagy improve vitiligo, as suggested by the study's title, or potentially worsen the progression of vitiligo, given that cell death is already present?

Comment: The image you included in your question is too low resolution to be readable.

Comment: I've change it. Also, the original images with full texts are available in the provided source. article.